# How wasteful would it be to call an empty function?

Tags: c++, function

These three points all relate to the same "empty function" question:

- How much processing time is wasted when calling an empty function?
- Would it make a huge impact to call 100, or even 1000 empty functions?
- What if these empty functions required arguments?

**Important edit** Is  calling an empty virtual function the same?

---

**Edit** 
SO basically you are all saying that in most cases the compiler will optimize this out.

But now I'm curious as this still applies to the question. What if there's a situation like so, where it is not known at compile time when an empty function will be called?
Will it immediately go to the stack then exit?

```
class base{
public:
    virtual void method() = 0;
};

class derived1: public base{
public:
    void method() { }
};

class derived2: public base{
public:
    void method(){ std::cout << " done something  "; }
};


int main()
{
    derived1 D1;
    derived2 D2;
    base* array[] = { &D1, &D2 };
    for( int i = 0; i < 1000; i ++)
    {
        array[0]->method();// nothing
        array[1]->method();// Something
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Profile it and find out.

Comment: The array of answers is probably `[none, no, nothing special]` at `-O2`.

Comment: "Wasteful" and "huge impact" are very vague terms - please try to narrow your question down to something more specific - what particular problem are you trying to solve ?

Comment: It'll depend on the compiler, optimization level, and whether the compiler can inline the call. The overhead might be 0 or more than 0. There's no general answer.

Comment: If you don't do anything funny the compiler will probably optimize and remove the calls. If not, an empty function call is pretty cheap but depends on the platform and compiler.

Comment: It does not matter, if your code is made beautiful

Comment: We need a "primarily compiler-based" closure reason, that's for sure...

Comment: Maybe the addition to the question changes things up a bit.. Sorry I didn't mention that part earlier.

Comment: Please note that I cannot say that empty functions necessarily makes your code beutiful. If you inherit a class and override a virtual method with an empty one, chances are it doesn't.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How much processing time is wasted when calling an empty function?

If you can make the compiler keep your empty function, there is the overhead of calling the function and the overhead of returning a value.  The overhead of calling depends on the number of parameters and how they are passed.

The actual overhead depends on the processor and how the compiler generates the code.
For example, the processor may have enough registers to contain every argument or the compiler may have to push arguments on a stack, and access them on a stack inside the function.

**Edit1:**
Processors like to process sequential data instructions.  Branches, jumps or function calls force the processors to change their instruction pointers and maybe reload their instruction cache.  Since these operations are not processing data instructions, they are wasting time and slowing down the performance of your program.  The degradation of performance from these branches is only noticeable in high performance programs (lots of data to process) or programs that need to meet critical deadlines (such as moving paper through a printer to avoid paper jams).

> Would it make a huge impact to call 100, or even 1000 empty functions?

Depends on your definition of "impact".  With the present speed of desktop processors, 100 or 1000 repetitions can occur in less than a second (more like less than 1 millisecond).

You would spend more time compiling (translating and linking) these functions.

> What if these empty functions required arguments?

Like I stated at the top, depends on the compiler and processor.

> Is calling an empty virtual function the same?

A virtual function call may require one or two more processor instructions; depends on the processor.

**Profile don't Assume**
Profiling is your friend.  Profiling will tell you how much time is spent in each function in your program.

**Don't Microoptimize**
Your concerns are called micro-optimizations.  You could be optimizing or worrying about code that only gets executed 20% or less of the time.  Or it is stuck waiting for an external process such as a mouse click or file I/O.

Put performance issues aside and focus on the correctness and robustness of your program.  A program that runs incorrectly is bad regardless of how fast or slow it is.  A program that can be easily broken or crashes is worthless regardless of how soon until the crash.

Only worry about performance when Users complain or your program is missing critical real-time deadlines (such as missing data from a streaming input source).

Comment: Couldn't agree with last paragraph. I believe one should consider performance while designing the system (before coding probably) rather than only when performance issues are hit.

Comment: @ShivendraMishra In my experiance, large code bases written by people constantly worried about optimisations are harder to read/maintain and more likely to contain bugs. Having worked on multiple legacy projects I have frequently fixed bugs (and even performance issues!) by deleting custom container definitions (likely beutifully optimal in the eyes of the writer), using std::algorithms and removing pointer/goto whichcraft in favour of simpler but branching code, which in almost all cases wasn't even at the bottleneck!

Comment: When considering performance, it's better to have a goal of "make sure it's fast enough that nobody complains" than a goal of "make it as fast as it possibly can be".  Unless you're in some kind of competition for efficiency (high-frequency trading, perhaps?), the latter is largely a waste of your time, and is likely to cause other aspects of your program (e.g. maintainability, readability) to suffer.

Comment: @ShivendraMishra That's the very definition of pre-optimization. Readability and maintainability are more important. If you're sacrificing those for optimizations that you might never need, you're creating unnecessary headaches for yourself when writing it and unnecessary headaches for anyone else who has to work with that code in the future.

Answer (score 14):

While it will most undoubtedly be optimized out completely by any decent compiler, here's a comparison.

```
void EmptyFunction() {}
void EmptyFunctionWithArgs(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e) {}
int EmptyFunctionRet() {return 0;}
int EmptyFunctionWithArgsRet(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e) {return 0;}

int main() {   
    EmptyFunction();
    EmptyFunctionWithArgs(0, 1, 2, 3, 4);
    EmptyFunctionRet();
    EmptyFunctionWithArgsRet(5, 7, 6, 8, 9);
}
```

**In Debug Mode** with VC++11 (which has very little if any optimization) here's what the calls look like:

`EmptyFunction();`

```
call    ?EmptyFunction@@YAXXZ            ; EmptyFunction
```

`EmptyFunctionWithArgs(0, 1, 2, 3, 4);`

```
push    4
push    3
push    2
push    1
push    0
call    ?EmptyFunctionWithArgs@@YAXHHHHH@Z    ; EmptyFunctionWithArgs
add     esp, 20                    ; 00000014H
```

`EmptyFunctionRet();`

```
call    ?EmptyFunctionRet@@YAHXZ        ; EmptyFunctionRet
```

`EmptyFunctionWithArgsRet(5, 7, 6, 8, 9);`

```
push    9
push    8
push    6
push    7
push    5
call    ?EmptyFunctionWithArgsRet@@YAHHHHHH@Z    ; EmptyFunctionWithArgsRet
add     esp, 20                    ; 00000014H
```

The int returning functions look like this:

`int EmptyFunctionRet()` and `int EmptyFunctionWithArgsRet()`

```
push   ebp
mov    ebp, esp
sub    esp, 192                ; 000000c0H
push   ebx
push   esi
push   edi
lea    edi, DWORD PTR [ebp-192]
mov    ecx, 48                    ; 00000030H
mov    eax, -858993460                ; ccccccccH
rep    stosd
xor    eax, eax
pop    edi
pop    esi
pop    ebx
mov    esp, ebp
pop    ebp
ret    0
```

The functions with no return value are the same, except they don't have the `xor eax, eax`.

**In Release Mode** VC++11 doesn't bother calling any of the functions.  But it does generate definitions for them.  The int returning functions look like this:

`int EmptyFunctionRet()` and `int EmptyFunctionWithArgsRet()`

```
xor    eax, eax
ret    0
```

Whereas the non-returning functions again remove the `xor eax, eax`.

You can see easily that the non-optimized functions are extremely bloated, and running them in a loop of however many times would absolutely cost time, whereas the loop itself would be removed with optimizations turned on.  So do yourself a favor folks, release with optimizations on.

You shouldn't worry about this, as it violates "Don't Optimize Yet."  If you're working with an obscure platform (like a 27-bit MCU), and your compiler is garbage, and your performance needs improvement, then you would profile your code to see where you need improvement (it's likely not empty function calls).  As it stands, this is really just an exercise that shows how much we should let the compiler do the heavy lifting.

**EDIT FOR YOUR EDIT:**

Interestingly, virtual functions are a known problem with optimizers, as they have extreme trouble figuring out where pointers are actually going to go.  Some contrived examples might eliminate the call, but if there's a call through a pointer, it's probably not going to be removed.

Compiling the following in VC++11 Release Mode:

```
class Object {
public:
    virtual void EmptyVirtual() {}
};

int main() {   
    Object * obj = new Object();
    obj->EmptyVirtual();
}
```

Yields the following snippet among the setup code:

```
mov     DWORD PTR [ecx], OFFSET ??_7Object@@6B@
mov     eax, DWORD PTR [ecx]
call    DWORD PTR [eax]
```

Which is the call to the virtual function.

Answer (score 6):

Try `g++-4.8 -O2 -S -o test.asm main.cpp && cat test.asm`. You will see that at `-O2` that `g++` optimizes it away.

For example with the following code:

```
void empty_function(int a, int b, int c) { }

int main() {
    int a = 42, b = a, c = a;
    empty_function(a, b, c); 
}
```

I don't see it called in the assembly output.

---

I followed pmr's advice and did the following get-up:

`Object.h`

```
#ifndef _OBJECT_H_
#define _OBJECT_H_

class Object {
 public:
  Object() { }
  void empty_function();
};

#endif
```

`Object.cpp`

```
#include "Object.h"

void Object::empty_function() { }
```

`main.cpp`

```
#include "Object.h"

int main() {
  Object object;
  object.empty_function();
}
```

Interestingly, it does call the empty function:

```
call    __main
leaq    47(%rsp), %rcx
call    _ZN6Object14empty_functionEv
xorl    %eax, %eax
addq    $56, %rsp
ret
```

Comment: So now, when you know that compilers are really smart, write code that are optimized for humans

Comment: @AndersLindén In the general case, yes. Such advice isn't so useful for performance critical code however. Compilers aren't omnipotent.

Comment: Fun exercise: What happens when the definition of the function is in a different translation unit or library?

Comment: It can be useful even in performance critical situations as proved

Comment: @Anders: But it's no excuse to not even think about it and try things out.

Comment: I see it a bit differently. If the customer is content with the performance of my program, there is no excuse improving it.

Comment: There are two kind of programmers, those that program for the customer, and those that program for God.

Comment: @pmr Add the `-flto` flag.  The compiler can't remove the call because it can't see across translation units.  `-flto` will run a link-time-optimization pass to look at that specifically.

Comment: @Sam I don't think I have that configured in my compiler.

Comment: Shucks.  FWIW, Clang/LLVM showcases it really well since one call of `opt -std-link-opts` removes the call specifically.

Comment: @SamCristall I wasn't saying that there is no way to optimize in such a situation. I just wanted to give remyabel a nudge to look beyond the simplest case.

Answer (score 0):

```
void nothing(void){}

int main(){
    for(int i = 0; i<100; ++i){
        nothing();
    }
}
```

When i fed through `g++` with the `-S` flag gave an assembly file doing the following;

**main()**

```
_main:
LFB1023:
    push    ebp
LCFI3:
    mov ebp, esp
LCFI4:
    and esp, -16
    sub esp, 16
    call    ___main
    mov DWORD PTR [esp+12], 0
    jmp L3
L4:
    call    __Z7nothingv
    add DWORD PTR [esp+12], 1
L3:
    cmp DWORD PTR [esp+12], 99
    jle L4
    mov eax, 0
    leave
LCFI5:
    ret
```

**nothing()**

```
__Z7nothingv:
LFB1022:
    push    ebp
LCFI0:
    mov ebp, esp
LCFI1:
    pop ebp
LCFI2:
    ret
```

So in this program we are basically pushing ebp, moving esp into ebp & popping ebp 100 times

Comment: Try that again with -O2 and you'll see it won't happen